# Why is classic if writing and inline if writing are not behaving the same way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I got this code

```
firstId = True
       
for x in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    firstId = False if firstId else print(str(x)+ " " + str(firstId))
    
print ("What is happening here ???")

firstId = True
       
for x in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    if firstId: 
        firstId = False
    else:
        print(str(x)+ " " + str(firstId))
```

And strangly i have this output

```
2 False
3 None
4 None
5 None
What is happening here ???
2 False
3 False
4 False
5 False
```

From my understanding both if statement should behave the same way.But the boolean is not.
I can't understand why the boolean somehow becomes None. Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: No, they should not and do not behave the same way. They are different constructions for different purposes. `firstId = False if firstId else print(str(x)+ " " + str(firstId))` always assigns a value to `firstId`, either False or None, which is the return value of a `print` call.

Comment: The `print` function returns `None` and you're assigning this.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I guess my tutorial was missing this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
firstId = False if firstId else print(str(x)+ " " + str(firstId))
```

is the same as

```
firstId = (False if firstId else print(str(x)+ " " + str(firstId)))
```

i.e.

```
if firstId:
    firstId = False
else:
    firstId = print(str(x)+ " " + str(firstId))
```

It always assigns a value to `firstId`, and the conditional expression on the right determines what that value is.

In the `else` case, the value is None, because `print(...)` returns None.

A conditional expression is not a one-line if statement. It is a different construction for a different purpose.

Comment: Got it i wrote : `firstId = expression1 if firstID else expression2`
How was i suppose to write to have : `exp1 if firstId else exp2`
with exp1 being 
`firstId = False`

Comment: You can't, because `firstId = False` is not an expression. Your version with the if-statement is more suited to this situation.

Comment: Perfectly clear, thank you